# What travel insurance meets the requirements of the Affordable Care Act and the Italian elective residence visa?

Tags: usa, insurance, schengen, italy

Our family is preparing to move from the US to Europe, and we're looking to find suitable health insurance to cover my wife and me and our infant son. We likely will spend more than a month back in the States during the upcoming year, so the ACA will require us to purchase an eligible policy or pay a penalty.

Also, since we're applying for an elective residence visa for Italy (a D-Visa), we're required to have insurance that provides at least $1M coverage per person.

What insurance provider offers policies that are both ACA-compliant and adequate for the Italian visa?

Comment: A type D visa isn't actually a Schengen visa, it's the name in Schengen parlance of a national long-stay visa. Similarly, you cannot get a Schengen residence permit that would allow you to reside everywhere in the Schengen area but only a national residence permit from a Schengen member state that will allow you to travel everwhere in the area but only to reside in that member state. Since they are not unified like type C visas, the exact requirements will depend on the specific country and visa you want to apply to and you should add that information to your question.

Comment: By the way, U.S. citizens and residents are exempt from the penalty if they qualify for the Foreign Earned Income Exclusion, either through the Physical Presence Test (330 days outside the U.S. during any 12-month period; the periods do not have to match the year, and can be overlapping), or the Bona Fide Residence Test (bona fide resident of the foreign country for the previous year and part of the current year).

Comment: I have the same question. Did you ever find the answer? user102008, The OP was pretty clear in stating he'll be visiting the US for longer than the Foreign Earned Income Exclusion period.

Comment: @lostdorje Someone who qualifies under the bona fide residence test can visit the US for more than 30 days while still taking the foreign earned income exclusion, therefore being exempt from the ACA penalty.

Answer (score 2):

Without endorsing any specific carrier, insurers do offer plans for expats, as well as for those who require coverage in both their home country and abroad. As examples, searching on 'global health insurance:'

- [Aetna](https://www.aetna.com/individuals-families/international-insurance.html)
- [IMG](https://www.imglobal.com/international-health-insurance/global-medical-insurance)
- [Cigna](https://www.cignaglobal.com/)
- [Allianz](https://www.internationalinsurance.com/apply/expat-plan/)
- [GeoBlue Global Medical](https://www.internationalinsurance.com/geo-blue/xplorer/)

Also returned in the Google search is this article on [researching international health insurance companies.](https://www.internationalinsurance.com/health/best-companies.php)